# Temporary Drupal hosting

Tags: database

I'm not entirely certain that this question belongs here but here goes. I've built a pretty basic Drupal site for a department at my University but now I need to migrate it from my laptop to the public. In order to do that I have to jump through a -lot- of hoops with the ITCS department of my University but the site needs to go live pretty soon (within the next 4 days or so) because it's currently hosted on my laptop and I'm leaving the country.

So, what I was wondering is: is there somewhere that I can put this thing for free for a while so that the folks I'm working with can get used to it and show it off (it's for grant purposes) while I work with ITCS to get it up on University servers?

I can't really do it and they don't have any one who can show them how (I'm working remotely) so it's been a pretty big hassle getting this thing off the ground.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pantheon](https://www.getpantheon.com/) will allow you to set up a dev site on their servers for free.  This will not support very many users unless you're willing to pay but is probably sufficient for a demo.

Answer (score 3):

I'd look for cheap shared hosting. Make sure you get PHP and MySql and some kind of temporary URL.

Answer (score 0):

hey use this for free hosting....

http://www.000webhost.com/554256.html

This is awesome you can host any drupal website having data upto 1500 MB.
But they support PHP 5.2 for free hosting. If you need 5.3 then go for paid...